# Vue.Js Filters to Computed - how to use?

Tags: javascript, number-formatting, vuejs2

**UPDATED DESCRIPTION**

When the user leaves the field I need to set the formatted value back into the field - that's why I was using the filters so when the user enters 10.1 and left the field then the field would automatically be updated to display 10.10

Sorry if I did not clarify that earlier

**Do you or does anyone have any idea?

Bert Solved!

I forked his CodePen and added a check for empty values so I could just display a blank (my own bus requirement):

[Forked Example](http://codepen.io/barbedCoil/pen/RpjZXq?editors=1010)

---

I have the following computed function that I converted from a 1.0 Filter.
**Purpose**: Format decimal amounts entered to have nnnn.nn type format so that entering 10.10 would return 10.10 instead of non-formatted 10.1.

I want to format on the fly for the user (their request not mine)

```
    computed:
    {
        decimalComputed:
        {
            get: function (value)
            {
                var newFloat = parseFloat(value);
                return newFloat.toFixed(2);
            },
            set: function (value)
            {
                var newFloat = parseFloat(value);
                return newFloat.toFixed(2);
            }
        },
    },
```

**The problem is that when I am trying to use it as a function I get an error telling me decimalComputed is NOT a function so I set it as a property in the html but then nothing is formatted.**

Here is an example of how I am calling:

```
<input :id="'cash_tips-' + index" type="text" 
    v-model="decimalComputed = tip.cash_tips" pattern="\d*" number />
```

I don't care if I don't use computed or not I just need to solve the problem:  format values as the after user enters them

Any help would be most welcome.

I will circle back in a couple of hours to update is need be

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use a small component in this case.

```
Vue.component("formatted-number",{
  props:["value", "decimals"],
  data(){
    return {
      internalValue: this.format(this.value)
    }
  },
  methods:{
    format(value){ return parseFloat(value).toFixed(this.decimals || 2);},
    onChange(){this.$emit('input', this.format(this.internalValue))}
  },
  template:'<input type="text" v-model="internalValue" @input="onChange" />'
})
```

Then use it in your template like this

```
<formatted-number v-model="tip.cash_tips" :decimals="2"></formatted-number>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/LWOxrG?editors=1010).

### Post Comment Edit

```
Vue.component("formatted-number",{
  props:["value", "decimals"],
  data(){
    return {
      internalValue: this.format(this.value)
    }
  },
  methods:{
    format(value){ return parseFloat(value).toFixed(this.decimals || 2);},
    onChange(){this.$emit('input', this.format(this.internalValue))},
    onBlur(){this.internalValue = this.format(this.internalValue)}
  },
  template:'<input type="text" v-model="internalValue" @input="onChange" @blur="onBlur" />'
})
```

Comment: Bert solution is a good solution, regarding your code, I do not think you can pass values to getters.

Comment: @MohammadAbuMusa `format` is not a getter. It's just a method. I made it a method because I use it to format internalValue initially.

Comment: sorry for the confusion I was talking about his original code, not yours. he is passing `value` to the `computed property`

Comment: @BertEvans Thank you.  I would give you 2 points if I could.  You helped me solve my problem and you gave me a solid, real, example of doing a quick component.

One followup:  Not having done a component before (we use vue 1.x for basic) - where does the component code go?  In it's own .js module or in same .js module where I need to use it.

Never mind about where to use - I just saw the example link, all is answered.  Thanks much!

Comment: @MohammadAbuMusa You are correct, that was my last attempt at passing data in according to docs on Vue

Comment: @BertEvans So after playing with this it gets me 1/2 there.
See updated description if you are willing to take a look

Comment: @Tab Updated. That should reset the displayed value to the formatted value when they leave the field.

Comment: @BertEvans Thank you, I appreciate the effort, components are new to me in production code so this is a huge help for me to learn and make use of